# Meteor Mongo getting specific value

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have the collection with the following values:

```
Plans.insert({
  location,
  address,
  date,
  time,
  notes,
  createdAt: new Date(), // current time
  owner: Meteor.userId(),
  username: Meteor.user().username,
  attendees: [
     {
        user: Meteor.user().username;
     },         
     {
        user: Meteor.user().username;
     },
  ],
});
```

But I was wondering how I could get the specific values of the array `attendees`.

So far I have tried `Plans.findOne({ _id: { attendees: [{user: Meteor.user().username},], }});` but it comes out to undefined.

I was also wondering how I could get the numeric value of each one, such as `attendees[0]` and `attendees[1]`.

Comment: "how I could get the specific values of the array attendees" - means what? Getting the document that has specific value in attendees array?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `$elemMatch`

```
Plans.findOne({attendees: {$elemMatch: {user: 'ABC'}}};
```

Comment: is there a way to get all collections that have that though?  `$elemMatch` only retrieves the first match, but I need all that apply.

Comment: you mean about documents , no collections rite ?

Comment: Yeah sorry I meant the documents.